How to fix the sequence number of the MAC frame header in 802.11b packets?
I am tring to fix the sequence number in the MAC frame header for 802.11b to 0 (or any number else).
I have tried modifying the mac80211 layer and the driver code for the WiFi network card (the nwtwork card
is QCA6174A and the driver version is ath10k) in the Linux Kernel, but even though the logs I print in the Kernel show that it's set to 0, the sequence number of packets in the air I'm catching with packet capture tools is still increasing (as shown in the figure below). Is this field reset in the firmware of the WiFi card? Or how can I fix the sequence number?
enter image description here
I also tried to turn off the offload of WiFi card after I set the sequence number in kernel:
$ ethtool --offload wlp3s0 rx off tx off
$ ethtool -K wlp3s0 gso off
But it still doesn't work.
